# How to refresh JWT Tokens using Angular Http Interceptor and RxJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, rxjs

I'm using two JWT tokens - `Refresh Token`(expires after 7 days) and `Access Token` (expires after 15 min). They are stored on `httpOnly cookies` and can be accessed via server. Refresh methods signs new token and store it on a cookie. I need to check if these tokens are expired after every request like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            const expirationToken = this.cookieService.get('tokenexp'); // access token expiration
            const expirationTokenRefresh = this.cookieService.get('tokenrefexp'); // refresh expiration
            
            // Refresh Token needs to be checked first
            if (Number(expirationTokenRefresh) < Date.now()) {
                // new refresh token is stored on cookie
                this.authService.refreshTokenRefresh();
                // this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(() => { ... });
            }
            // next we check Access Token
            if (Number(expirationToken) < Date.now()) {
              // new access token is stored on cookie
              this.authService.refreshToken();
         // this.authService.refreshTokenRefresh().subscribe(() => { ... });
            }
            return next.handle(req.clone({
                withCredentials: true
            }));
    }

}

// auth service
refreshToken() {
  return this.http.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/refreshtoken`);
}
refreshTokenRefresh() {
  return this.http.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/refreshtokenref`);
}
```

Here is `Express` back-end methods:

```js
//routes
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/refreshtoken', user.refreshToken);
router.get('/refreshtokenref', user.refreshTokenRefresh);

// refresh access token method
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const moment = require('moment');
const User = require('../models/user');
exports.refreshToken = wrap(async(req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ refresh_token: req.cookies['tokenref'] });
    if (user) {
        const newToken = await jwt.sign(
            { email: user.email, userId: user._id, role: user.role },
            process.env.JWT_Key,
            { expiresIn: '15m' });
        const expiresAt = moment().add(900, 'second');
        res.cookie('tokenexp', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()), { maxAge: 3000000000, secure: true});
        res.cookie('token', newToken, { maxAge: 3000000000, secure: true, httpOnly: true });
        res.status(200).json({success: true});
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({success: false, message: 'Sessão expirou.'});
    }
});
```

How can I make it work using `RxJS Observables`? I may send one request to refresh a token, and then another request to refresh second token, and finally the original request with updated cookies. In summary, I may need to send requests before my original request.
Also there is problem: `AuthInterceptor` shouldn't be called after request one or two (tokens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mergeMap to sequentially check the validity of token.

```
return of(Number(expirationTokenRefresh) < Date.now()).pipe(
  mergeMap(expire => expire
    ? this.authService.refreshTokenRefresh()
    : of(Number(expirationToken) < Date.now())
  ),
  mergeMap(expire => expire
    ? this.authService.refreshToken()
    : of(true)
  ),
  mergeMap(ok => next.handle(req.clone({ withCredentials: true })))
)
```

Comment: How to avoid multiple HttpInterceptor calls while navigating between `mergeMap`? I'm trying to send requests with `HttpBackend` like this `const http = new HttpClient(this.handler);
    return this.http.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/refreshtoken`);` but it doesn't work very well

Comment: Good question. it's not a very straight forward setup for this case. Could you open up a new question for that, i'l try to answer it.

Comment: ok made another question. There you go: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781145/how-to-avoid-multiple-httpinterceptor-calls-while-navigating-between-rxjs-mergem)